# how to assign an whole array to dictionary in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary

How to assign an array to dictionary in c#

below code is not working

```
ArrayList conf_list = new ArrayList();
var variations = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

conf_list.Add ("hi");
conf_list.Add ("bye");
conf_list.Add ("ss");
conf_list.Add ("fefe");
conf_list.Add ("gg");
conf_list.Add ("qwq");
conf_list.Add ("trt");

variations["available"] = conf_list;
```

Error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.ArrayList' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'  ConsoleApplication1 c:\users\administrator\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs 27  Active
```

How to push hole array at one time to dictionay??

Note: i dont want to use this method

```
variations["available"] = new List<string> { "hi","bye" };
```

Comment: You probably mean to use `List<string>` instead of `ArrayList`

Comment: If you declare the dictionary as `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` why do you use an `ArrayList` instead of a `List<string>`?

Comment: Also note that neither `ArrayList` nor `List<T>` are arrays. And note that the compiler is telling you exactly what's wrong: "Cannot implicitly convert type `'System.Collections.ArrayList'` to `'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'`" They're not the same thing - so don't try to use them as if they were.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
var variations = new Dictionary<string, ArrayList>();
```

or

```
List<string> conf_list = new List<string>();
```

The two types can not be used interchangeably.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert that `ArrayList` into a `List<string>`. This can be done like that:

```
variations["available"] = conf_list.OfType<string>().ToList();
```

The reason for your error is that `conf_list` is of type `ArrayList` which is not implicitly convertible to `List<string>`.

By using `OfType<string>()` you get an enumeration of `string`s and with `ToList()` you turn this enumeration into an `List<string>` which then can be added to your dictionary.

---

Alternatively you can declare your `conf_list` as `List<string>` right from the start.

```
List<string> conf_list = new List<string>();
conf_list.Add ("hi");
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
List<string> lstString = new List<string>();
var variations = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
variations.Add("available", lstString);
```

if you want to add `ArrayList` into `Dictionary` so you need to create `Dictionary` some thing like ...

```
var variations = new Dictionary<string, ArrayList>();
```